# Cannot Use Selenium Python Linux Mint

Tags: python-3.x, linux, selenium-webdriver

I've been trying to use do some simple tasks on my travel laptop using Python and Selenium. On literally every other machine, both Linux and Windows, that I have, it works without any issues. On this laptop - running Linux Mint 22, I just can't get it to even open a browser. I've tried Firefox, Chrome, it always crashes. Here's an example:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


options = Options()
options.binary_location = '/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable'
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path='/home/garri/Downloads/chromedriver_linux64')
driver.get('http://google.com/')
```

and the error message that results from that is:

raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: no chrome binary at /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable

I've tried the following things:

sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable

sudo chmod +x /home/garri/Downloads/chromedriver_linux64/chromedrive

but nothing seems to work. Again, on any other computer it works without any issues. Any ideas ?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the anaconda (base) that was running. I had set it to launch automatically and it was (for some reason) messing things up.

Once I removed the anaconda (base) from starting automatically and tested it with the python 3.10 that was the default version of my machine, I could launch google chrome.